# How can I access a value in the JSP from the CONTROLLER?

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, controller, setattribute

```
<div>
    <input name="wordCount" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start" onclick=""/>
</div>
```

When I click 'start' button, I want to access to this input value from controller. But, I don't want to use form tag. Can I set as a session value with Javascript? If yes, how do I do it? Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use an ajax call to send your data to a controller.
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
<input name="wordCount" id="wordCount" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start" onclick="ajaxCall()"/>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
 function ajaxCall() {
    var value = $('#wordCount').val();
    $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'controller.htm',
            data:{value:value},
            success : function(data) {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/controller" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String restructure(Model model, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
    @RequestParam(value = "value",required=false) String value){
        System.out.println("Value from JSP "+ value);
    }
```

Hope it helps :)